# Help with SAR model interpretation

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, autoregressive, spatial-correlation, spatial-interaction-model

I am working on a research project that investigates the effect of land subsidence and flood risk on property prices. I have used the Spatial Autoregressive (SAR) model to estimate the direct, indirect, and total effects of these variables on property prices, but I am not sure how to interpret the results and calculate the percentage of the effect. The statistical result is as follows:

```
#p=rho, T=theta, and L=lambda
#SLX Spatially Lagged X y=Xß+WXT+e
reg.SAR <- lagsarlm(reg.eqTD, data = spat.data, listw1)
summary(reg.SAR)
## 
## Call:lagsarlm(formula = reg.eqTD, data = spat.data, listw = listw1)
## 
## Residuals:
##       Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
## -1.364120 -0.281887 -0.012993  0.265194  0.991845 
## 
## Type: lag 
## Coefficients: (asymptotic standard errors) 
##                Estimate  Std. Error z value  Pr(>|z|)
## (Intercept)    9.00565485  0.50238808 17.9257 < 2.2e-16
## land           0.00353826  0.00020556 17.2131 < 2.2e-16
## home           0.00221332  0.00039928  5.5432 2.969e-08
## floors        -0.04842446  0.05873681 -0.8244  0.409695
## d.floor_ce     0.05856431  0.03403236  1.7208  0.085279
## prox_ES        0.00202911  0.00769392  0.2637  0.791988
## prox_JHS      -0.03436720  0.01107906 -3.1020  0.001922
## prox_SHS       0.01358471  0.00814086  1.6687  0.095176
## proc_UNIV     -0.01277332  0.00990953 -1.2890  0.197400
## prox_TRAIN    -0.00979211  0.01044970 -0.9371  0.348722
## prox_BUS      -0.00136776  0.00734828 -0.1861  0.852341
## prox_HSPT     -0.00721804  0.01124824 -0.6417  0.521065
## prox_CBD       0.01054717  0.01048007  1.0064  0.314222
## subsidence    -0.93642703  0.35687624 -2.6240  0.008692
## slope          0.07551687  0.05048210  1.4959  0.134676
## flood         -0.11530988  0.06399816 -1.8018  0.071582
## income         0.00015392  0.00003009  5.1154 3.131e-07
## 
## Rho: 0.19033, LR test value: 23.73, p-value: 1.1084e-06
## Asymptotic standard error: 0.038385
##     z-value: 4.9584, p-value: 7.1069e-07
## Wald statistic: 24.586, p-value: 7.1069e-07
## 
## Log likelihood: -362.3157 for lag model
## ML residual variance (sigma squared): 0.13951, (sigma: 0.37352)
## Number of observations: 829 
## Number of parameters estimated: 19 
## AIC: 762.63, (AIC for lm: 784.36)
## LM test for residual autocorrelation
## test value: 6.1989, p-value: 0.012783

impacts(reg.SAR, listw = listw1)
## Impact measures (lag, exact):
##                  Direct      Indirect         Total
## land          0.003559770  8.102129e-04  0.0043699826
## home          0.002226776  5.068200e-04  0.0027335956
## floors       -0.048718888 -1.108855e-02 -0.0598074347
## d.floor_ce    0.058920393  1.341044e-02  0.0723308287
## prox_ES       0.002041449  4.646391e-04  0.0025060876
## prox_JHS     -0.034576152 -7.869623e-03 -0.0424457749
## prox_ShS      0.013667309  3.110716e-03  0.0167780248
## prox_UNIV    -0.012850981 -2.924917e-03 -0.0157758980
## prox_TRAIN   -0.009851644 -2.242260e-03 -0.0120939035
## prox_BUS     -0.001376073 -3.131978e-04 -0.0016892707
## prox_HSPT    -0.007261929 -1.652834e-03 -0.0089147631
## prox_CBD      0.010611301  2.415160e-03  0.0130264616
## subsidence   -0.942120612 -2.144291e-01 -1.1565497385
## slope         0.075976021  1.729234e-02  0.0932683626
## flood        -0.116010977 -2.640440e-02 -0.1424153807
## income        0.000154860  3.524654e-05  0.0001901065
```

Can you please help me understand how to interpret the SAR model and how to calculate the percentage of the effect of land subsidence and flood on property price discounts? I would appreciate it if you could explain the steps and formulas that are needed for this calculation. I already studied the explanation of how to interpret the coefficient of spatial model, yet The Golgher explanation did not help me so much.